# Scaling a sprite in unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so my sprite will always be the same proportion for all screen sizes. Is there a way that I can scale my sprite to be a certain width and or height compared to the rest of the screen? I have tried multiple ways but everything I have looked up goes over my head. Is there an easy way to implement this? Or any way at all in Unity? Thanks for any help. Here is an image to help further what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

I want the detailed image to be the size of the black and green rectangle. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to convert from pixels per world unit like so:

```
     Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.orthographicSize - (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.texture.height / GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.pixelsPerUnit));
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer so as future users know it was correct!

Comment: @gjttt1 i cant for 2 days since i posted